# Can ejs and jsx work together?

Tags: express, webpack, ejs, reactjs

I have a navigation bar that is created by jsx as seen below.

See the `href="/users/<%= user.username %>`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, Glyphicon, NavDropdown, MenuItem } from 'react-bootstrap';

const navbarInstance = (
  <Navbar inverse>
    <Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Toggle>
    <Glyphicon className="glyphicon" glyph="align-justify" />
    </Navbar.Toggle>
      <Navbar.Brand>
        <a href=".">Some brand name</a>
      </Navbar.Brand>
    </Navbar.Header>
    <Navbar.Collapse>
      <Nav className="nav">
        <NavItem eventKey={1} href="/users/<%= user.username %>">My Page</NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey={2} href="#">Forum</NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey={3} href="./status">Status</NavItem>
        <NavItem eventKey={4} href="#">Donate</NavItem>
      </Nav>
      <Nav pullRight>
        <NavDropdown eventKey={5} title="Account">
          <MenuItem eventKey="5.1" href="./edit">My Page Setup</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem eventKey="5.2" href="./logout">Log Out</MenuItem>
        </NavDropdown>
      </Nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
  </Navbar>
);

export default navbarInstance;
```

When I click on My Page, browser says `"Failed to decode param '%3C%=%20user.username%20%%3E'"`.
I also use webpack and express.js.

How can I get around this?